# react native app in google pixel 2 XL shows transparent bottom button bar

Tags: react-native, google-pixel

while trying to run my app on google pixel 2 XL the softkeys bar remains transparent which is somehow handled in remaining pixel phones(black background behind the softkeys). Is there a way to handle that from your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution just changed following lines in 'android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml'

```
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
</style>`
```

earlier it was true there